# Maven EAR project distribution for multiple application server?

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have a maven project which generate zip generated from ant scripts. Then this zip is deployed to specific application server again using ant script. this is very complex for maintenance. Now we move to use maven for building zip, so what is standard way to doing with respect to developer and client

1. How to handle application server specific deployment(e.g for weblogic and jboss) Do I need to create 2 zip for each server?
2. How to handle global configuration parameter like database, product specific settings. Where to put them, and how it use by developer and client?
3. The installation of application sever is need to integrate with build cycle or what is best practice for it?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer based on my experience:

1. I use maven profiles for this. Especially since there are beans (classes) that are specific to only one app server at a time. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
2. maven supports placeholders. One build for every single environment: dev/qa/prod,etc. All you need is the properties file. (this is similar to properties in ant)
3. You do not need (usually, unless you have integration tests that are tight to the app server - and if you do, it seems wrong) an app server for the build itself.

Comment: Point 3 would depend on what "deployment" means. If deployment includes starting and stopping a remote server, then yes. If it is only to put the zip file somewhere, then no.

Comment: If i don`t have any dependency on application container. i want my application to run on any container. My EAR should directly run on any container then what will be standard ear structure.